# How can I read *.csv files that have numbers with commas using pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to read a *.csv file that have numbers with commas.

For example,

File.csv

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
2016/11/09,12:10:00,'4355,'4358,'4346,'4351,1,201 # The last value is 1201, not 201
2016/11/09,12:09:00,'4361,'4362,'4353,'4355,1,117 # The last value is 1117, not 117
2016/11/09,12:08:00,'4364,'4374,'4359,'4360,10,175 # The last value is 10175, not 175
2016/11/09,12:07:00,'4371,'4376,'4360,'4365,590
2016/11/09,12:06:00,'4359,'4372,'4358,'4369,420
2016/11/09,12:05:00,'4365,'4367,'4356,'4359,542
2016/11/09,12:04:00,'4379,'1380,'4360,'4365,1,697 # The last value is 1697, not 697
2016/11/09,12:03:00,'4394,'4396,'4376,'4381,1,272 # The last value is 1272, not 272
2016/11/09,12:02:00,'4391,'4399,'4390,'4393,524
...
2014/07/10,12:05:00,'10195,'10300,'10155,'10290,219,271 # The last value is 219271, not 271
2014/07/09,12:04:00,'10345,'10360,'10185,'10194,235,711 # The last value is 235711, not 711
2014/07/08,12:03:00,'10339,'10420,'10301,'10348,232,050 # The last value is 242050, not 050
```

It actually has 7 columns, but the values of the last column sometimes have commas and pandas take them as extra columns.

My questions is, if there are any methods with which I can make pandas takes only the first 6 commas and ignore the rest commas when it reads columns, or if there are any methods to delete commas after the 6th commas(I'm sorry, but I can't think of any functions to do that.)

Thank you for reading this :)

Comment: Are the quotes a part of the actual file?

Comment: Oh, they are not. I edited to show irregularities.

Comment: Do you want to do this only in pandas? Or are you also open to options where you can do some pre processing and then give the result to pandas?

Comment: Does the extra comma appear only in the last column (possibly)?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. I'm open to manipulating it not only in pandas. I'm looking up some string methods, but it's not easy to grasp how I can do this job.

Comment: Yes, they only (sometimes) appear only in the last column.

Comment: There is no way to do this unless you can guarantee that at least one row's last number is <=999 (or unless you know a priori how many columns there are, but if you knew that this wouldn't be a problem in the first place). But if you do have such a row, then you can find the number of commas in that row, and remove the rightmost commas from every row so that they all have that number of commas. Then the commas will have been removed from the last entry in each row.

Comment: One more way to solve your problem. Check my solution below.

Comment: PLEASE edit your question to show exactly what is in your data file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of it in Python without having to save the data into a new file. The idea is to clean the data and put in a dictionary-like format for pandas to grab it and turn it into a dataframe. The following should constitute a decent starting point:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

# Import the data
data = open('prices.csv').readlines()

# Split on the first 6 commas
data = [x.strip().replace("'","").split(",",6) for x in data]

# Get the headers
headers = [x.strip() for x in data[0]]

# Get the remaining of the data
remainings = [list(map(lambda y: y.replace(",",""), x)) for x in data[1:]]

# Create a dictionary-like container
output = defaultdict(list)

# Loop through the data and save the rows accordingly
for n, header in enumerate(headers):
    for row in remainings:
        output[header].append(row[n])

# Save it in an ordered dictionary to maintain the order of columns
output = OrderedDict((k,output.get(k)) for k in headers)
# Convert your raw data into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(output)

# Print it
print(df)
```

This yields:

```
         Date      Time  Open  High   Low Close Volume
0  2016/11/09  12:10:00  4355  4358  4346  4351   1201
1  2016/11/09  12:09:00  4361  4362  4353  4355   1117
2  2016/11/09  12:08:00  4364  4374  4359  4360  10175
3  2016/11/09  12:07:00  4371  4376  4360  4365    590
4  2016/11/09  12:06:00  4359  4372  4358  4369    420
5  2016/11/09  12:05:00  4365  4367  4356  4359    542
6  2016/11/09  12:04:00  4379  1380  4360  4365   1697
7  2016/11/09  12:03:00  4394  4396  4376  4381   1272
8  2016/11/09  12:02:00  4391  4399  4390  4393    524
```

The starting file (`prices.csv`) is the following:

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
2016/11/09,12:10:00,'4355,'4358,'4346,'4351,1,201
2016/11/09,12:09:00,'4361,'4362,'4353,'4355,1,117
2016/11/09,12:08:00,'4364,'4374,'4359,'4360,10,175
2016/11/09,12:07:00,'4371,'4376,'4360,'4365,590
2016/11/09,12:06:00,'4359,'4372,'4358,'4369,420
2016/11/09,12:05:00,'4365,'4367,'4356,'4359,542
2016/11/09,12:04:00,'4379,'1380,'4360,'4365,1,697
2016/11/09,12:03:00,'4394,'4396,'4376,'4381,1,272
2016/11/09,12:02:00,'4391,'4399,'4390,'4393,524
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Abdou! This method is so straightforward that I can solve the problem, and further, teaches me new approaches to use Python. I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to solve your problem.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

l1 =[]
with open('/home/yusuf/Desktop/c1') as f:
    headers = map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readline().strip('\n').split(','))
    for a in f.readlines():
        b = re.findall("(.*?),(.*?),'(.*?),'(.*?),'(.*?),'(.*?),(.*)",a)
        l1.append(list(b[0]))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=l1, columns=headers)
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(",",""))
df
```

Output:

[image]

Regex Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/o1zxtO/2

Comment: This looks like rows 3,4,5 and 8 have a problem e.g. row 3 has close == 4365,590 and volume == 0 but should be close 4365 and volume 590

Comment: @JohnMachin Oh. My bad. I misread his question. It's even simpler than that now. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `pandas` can't handle that, but you can easily fix the final column. An approach in Python

```
    with open('yourfile.csv') as csv, open('newcsv.csv','w') as result:
        for line in csv:
            columns = line.split(',')
            if len(columns) > COLUMNAMOUNT:
                columns[COLUMNAMOUNT-1] += ''.join(columns[COLUMNAMOUNT:])
            result.write(','.join(columns[COLUMNAMOUNT-1]))
```

Now you can load the new csv in to pandas. Other solutions can be AWK or even shell scripting.

Comment: Thank you for your help, kabanus! Thanks to you, I have decided to study more about csv library. This is such a simple method and easy to understand the logic. Thank you  again!

Comment: You can open the `result` file with a context manager too,  and it's always risky to name variables the same as standard library modules. If later on you want to use the `csv` module that might pose problems

Comment: @MaartenFabré I've only recently started using it, and it seemed like overkill, I'll accept. Is there a way to define multiple variables with the same with statements? NM found it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess pandas cant handle it so I would do a pre-processing with Perl to generate a new cvs and work on it.

Using Perl [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) can help you in this situation

```
perl -pne '$_ = join("|", split(/,/, $_, 7) )' < input.csv > output.csv
```

Then you can use the usual read_cvs on the output file with the seperator as |

Comment: Thank you, Astish Sai! I don't know much about Perl, but I think it's the simplest way to deal with the problem if I have a large amount of data!

Comment: @maynull I am glad I could help. If you think the solution works for the problem you mentioned be sure to tick mark the answer so it can help other as well